# A MessageReceived handler is blocking the gateway task

Tags: c#, .net, discord, discord.net

I want to send a message to everyone but I always get "A MessageReceived handler is blocking the gateway task." when downloading Users.

```
        [Command("testrole")]
        public async Task dmeveryone()
        {
            var guild = Program._client.GetGuild(Context.Guild.Id) as IGuild;
            await Context.Guild.DownloadUsersAsync();
            await Task.Delay(500);
            var users = await guild.GetUsersAsync();

            var recipients = users
                .OfType<IGuildUser>()
                .Where
                (
                    u => !u.IsBot && !u.IsWebhook
                );
            var tasks = recipients
                .Select
                (
                    r => r.SendMessageAsync("Hi")
                );
            try
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
            catch
            {
                var exceptions = tasks.Where(t => t.Exception != null)
                                      .Select(t => t.Exception);
            }
        }
```

this is how I use it, I tried using:

```
        [Command("testrole", RunMode.Async)]
```

but that won't work aswell..

Comment: `[Command("testrole", RunMode = RunMode.Async)]`

Comment: Please be aware that it is against Discord's TOS to send mass DM ads. It sounds like that is not your intention, but for me I had my account disabled for just allowing people to talk to their friends via DMs. Though this was resolved I can't say you will get the same result.